# Rollup Plugin Serve History API Fallback not working

Tags: javascript, rollupjs, svelte, svelte-3

i am using rollup for my svelte app. I install the package `rollup-plugin-serve` from npm to us the `historyApiFallback` so i can serve any url in my spa app.

https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-serve

my config looks like this:

```js
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve'

serve({
   contentBase: 'dist',
   port: 5000,
   historyApiFallback: true,
   historyApiFallback: 'index.html'
}),
```

Here is my full `rollup.config.js`

```js
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import svelte_preprocess_postcss from 'svelte-preprocess-postcss';
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve'

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;
export default {
   input: 'src/main.js',
   output: {
      format: 'iife',
      sourcemap: true,
      name: 'app',
      file: 'dist/main.js',
   },
   plugins: [
      svelte({
         dev: !production,
         preprocess: {
            style: svelte_preprocess_postcss(),
         },
         css: css => {
            css.write('dist/components.css');
         },
      }),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      postcss({
         extract: true,
      }),
      serve({
         contentBase: 'dist',
         host: 'localhost',
         port: 5000,
         historyApiFallback: true
      }),
      !production && livereload('dist'),
      production && terser(),
   ],
};
```

But this code doesn't work. When i serve to `localhost:5000/solutions/technic` i still get 404 Not Found Error.

Anything an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `'/index.html'` instead of `'index.html'`, like:

```
serve({
   contentBase: 'dist',
   port: 5000,
   historyApiFallback: '/index.html'
}),
```

Or use `historyApiFallback: true` ([`/index.html` is used as default](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-serve/blob/master/src/index.js#L48)):

```
serve({
   contentBase: 'dist',
   port: 5000,
   historyApiFallback: true
}),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but both methods not working, i still get 404 as error....

Comment: is your `index.html` in the `dist` directory?

Comment: yes sure, i am using the default svelte project environment with rollup.js

Comment: That's exactly what I've done to try reproducing your issue. can you maybe add the full rollup config your using to the question?

Comment: please take a look at my updated question... I hope this helps to solve the issue...